# Call Python code with argument `\addplot {\py{1+\x}};`

Tags: pgfplots, python, pythontex

The `pythontex` package allows us to do evaluate Python in LaTeX simply by `\py{1+3}`. However, this is not possible inside an `addplot`. A solution is wrapping the entire `tikzpicture` inside a substitute environment `\pys`, which substitutes `!{1+3}` with `4`. However, I would like the result to depend on `\x`, which is not possible in this 'solution'.

How would it be possible to evaluate a piece of Python code with an argument from LaTeX, like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot {\py{1+\x}};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a `declare function={...}` and inside it call python function.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for your suggestion, but `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{\pgfmathparse{\noexpand\py{1+#1}}}` and `\addplot {func(x)};` gives an undefined control sequence error  for `\pytx@type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{\pys{\pgfmathparse{!{str(1+float('#1'[2:-1])*(-1 if '#1'[0] == '2' else 1))}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Appearantly PGFplots or Tikz works with strange numbers of the form `2Y4.1665201e0`, inwhich the first two letters are `1Y` if it is positive and `2Y` if it is negative.

Perhaps I need to do something with `\pgfmathfloatvalueof`?